# NVDA is reading button aria-label on click but not on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility, nvda

I have created a slideshow for a website using W3Schools HTML code (from here: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp)

It all works fine except that I cannot get NVDA to read any title or aria-label attached to the previous and next arrows on hover. It only reads on click, which is too late for someone using a screen reader.

I've changed the W3Schools code from actual buttons to this:

```html
<div class="direction prev" tabindex="0" onclick="plusSlides(-1)" role="button" aria-label="previous">❮</div>
```

```html
<div class="direction next" tabindex="0" onclick="plusSlides(1)" role="button" aria-label="next">❯</div>
```

and tried several combinations including:

1. adding ids to a span with text and then referencing it with aria-labelledby in the button div
2. using `title="Previous Slide"`
3. using a special `class="visually-hidden"` using the clip method to hide the text (already used in the menu, but it doesn't read that, either)
4. various other similar options, to no avail.

What can I do to make NVDA read the label/text on hover? JavaScript is ok, but no jQuery, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the issue where nvda did not read the aria-label assigned to Icon or IconButton on hover. I wrapped the icon with span, set the role as img and assigned aria-label to span.

Previous:

```
 <IconButton
    aria-label="Some icon"
    role="button"
 >
     <TodayIcon aria-label="Today"/>
 </IconButton>
```

Current:

```
 <IconButton
    role="button"
  >
      <span role="img" aria-label="Today">
        <TodayIcon />
      </span>
 </IconButton>
```

Comment: Not working - by my testing NVDA absolutely does not read title and arial-label attributes on hover.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use aria-describedby="previous" or "next" So NVDA can read it. More information here: https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/labelling/a-aria-describedby/

If it does not work I am sorry. Let me know so I can delete

Comment: [`aria-describedby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute) takes the id of the element that contains the description of the element, not the description itself. You can see that in the linked article, where the attribute points to a `span` with the associated id.

Comment: You are right... aria-label is the correct attribute for this.. hmm.. maybe its the browser that you are using. I hope this link might help you finding a solution of your problem https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/7807

Comment: Thanks. aria-label doesn't work with NVDA, but I did find a solution which I'll post here.

Comment: Did anyone find a fix for this? @Gillian do you mind sharing that solution.

Comment: Yes, finally. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works. I haven't included the JavaScript as it's not relevant to this post.

```css
.gallery /*code for this demo only */ {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 1rem 0;
 border: 1px solid red;
 height: 50px;
}
.prev,
.next {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 22px;
  color: var(--dark-green);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border: none;
  user-select: none;
  left: 1rem;
}
.next {
  left: unset;
  right: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.visually-hidden {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="direction prev" tabindex="0" onclick="plusSlides(-1)" role="button">❮<span class="visually-hidden">Previous slide</span></div>
<div class="direction next" tabindex="0" onclick="plusSlides(1)" role="button">❯<span class="visually-hidden">Next slide</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got there in the end. I needed to move the forward and back symbols inside the spans and, as @robariissa01 said, I need to use the 'aria-label'. The code for the buttons is now this:

```
<div id="dp" class="direction prev" tabindex="0" onclick="plusSlides(-1)" role="button" aria-labelledby="ps"><span id="ps" for="dp" aria-label="Previous slide">❮</span></div>
<div id="dn" class="direction next" tabindex="0" onclick="plusSlides(1)" role="button" aria-labelledby="ns"><span id="ns" for="dn" aria-lable="Next slide">❯</span></div>
```